# Including another Makefile results in a failed build, why?

Tags: makefile, build, gnu-make

### Problem

Including an external Makefile makes my previously stable build fail with the following error :

> make: *** No rule to make target 'build/main.o', needed by 'all'.  Stop.

### Context

The context is that I currently manage the build of each of my projects with one Makefile per project. Since the projects Makefiles have a lot of redundancy, I want to put the common things in an external Makefile that will be included in each project's Makefile.

### Minimal example to reproduce the issue

In this simple and minimalist example I try to build srcs/main.c into build/main.o and I also try to display what is inside the variable `FOO` which in is `tools.mk` :

Folder structure :

```
|   Makefile
|
+---build
|       (main.o)
+---mkf
|       tools.mk
|
\---srcs
        main.c
```

Content of **Makefile** :

```
include ./mkf/tools.mk

mkfile_path :=$(realpath $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST)))
current_dir :=$(dir $(mkfile_path))

VPATH = $(current_dir)/srcs
./build/%.o: %.c
    @echo $< $@
    gcc $< -o $@

all: ./build/main.o test
    @echo Done ! 

test:
    @echo Testing include : $(FOO)  

.PHONY: all test
```

Content of **tools.mk** :

```
FOO = 42
```

Content of **main.c** (basic hello world) :

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{   
    printf("Hello, world!");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
} /*main*/
```

Now basically my problem is that if I place myself in the root folder and type `make all`, the build will fail with the error mentioned above. However if I comment the line `include ./mkf/tools.mk` the build succeeds. Thus I guess it fails because of the include line, but I cannot figure out why.

Can someone enlighten me on this ?

The build is performed with `GNU Make 4.2` on `Windows 7 64-bits`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

```
mkfile_path :=$(realpath $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST)))
```

That yields the path of the last included makefile, which is `./mkf/tools.mk`. See [Other Special Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Special-Variables) for details.

A fix:

```
mkfile_path :=$(realpath $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST)))
current_dir :=$(dir $(mkfile_path))
include ./mkf/tools.mk
```

Comment: Wow, that was tricky! Thank you for your answer. I'll try in a few days only but I'll not forget to accept your answer if it works :-)